# Revision edit summary inaccurate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revision-history

When making several edits in close succession, these edits are combined together into a single revision. However in this manner, the summary may no longer reflect the combined edit.

Consider the summary of [revision 9](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44405687/revisions) which reads

> added 1 character in body

But more than one character was added since two different edits have been merged.

Answer (score 3):

Only when you leave the summary box empty when submitting an edit will it be set automatically. Subsequent edits within the grace period let you *update* the summary (prefilling the summary box for you), if you don't it'll be left to the initial auto-generated summary and nothing changes.

In other words, this is by design. You are given the opportunity to correct your edit, and provide a better summary in the process.

If you want a new auto-generated summary, *clear* the summary box when you edit again; a new auto-generated comment will be appended to the previous, in the form

> *changes of first edit; changes of second edit*, etc.

If you use a custom summary instead, it will overwrite the previous version entirely.